# Azure Data Factory (ETL) from MongoDB to Azure Synapse Anlytics - Date Conversion

Tags: mongodb, azure, etl, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am building ETL pipeline using Azure DataFactory from MongoDB to Azure Synapse Anlytics.

This is my sample document

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62b6f74ce3a7b8ee664c675d"),
    "event_name" : "click_search",
    "screen_name" : "home",
    "product_sku" : "",
    "screen_id" : "5005",
    "action_id" : "1023",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2022-06-25T16:53:48.000+05:00")
}
```

I used simple Copy Data activity and then preview data for source (MongoDB) is showed me like this

```json
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "62b6f74ce3a7b8ee664c675d"
      },
    "event_name": "click_search",
    "screen_name": "home",
    "product_sku": "",
    "screen_id": "5005",
    "action_id": "1023",
    "created_on": {
      "$date": 1656158028000
       }
}
```

**My First question is why date is coming in different format in datafactory?**

**Secondly**

while mapping it show me like this
[image]

due to this when I ran pipeline it gives this error

```
    Message=Column 'created_on' contains an invalid value '1656158028000'. Cannot convert 
    '1656158028000'to type 'DateTime'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,
    ''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid 
    DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,'
```

I tried to find this issue in documentation [Copy data from or to MongoDB using Azure Data Factory or Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties)

but didn't get any luck, please let me know what's happening under the hood? Why MongoDB send date like this and how can we resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores date as [BSON date](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#date)

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and future.

For your case, you can use [toUTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#toUTC) to convert UNIX timestamp to proper date in ADF. One thing to note is that MongoDB stores unix timestamp in milliseconds, so you may need to divide by 1000 before converting to UTC date.